# JQuery replaceWith apaga elemento ao fazer a troca em varios lugares

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou com um problema na chamada da função `replaceWith` do **JQuery**.

Eu tenho uma variável que está armazenando uma estrutura HTML, essa estrutura eu quero renderizar em vários lugares diferentes (isso funciona quando mando substituir varios blocos de uma vez), quando faço a troca usando o `replaceWith` pela segunda vez, ele apaga o lugar onde fiz a troca pela primeira vez, e assim sucessivamente.

> Como faço para substituir o conteúdo em outro lugar, sem apagar onde já tem?

Obs: não posso fazer a troca em vários lugares de uma vez, tenho que fazer em elemento por elemento.

**Exemplo:**

```
<div class="bloco1"></div>
<div class="bloco2"></div>

<div id="conteudo">Isso deve ir para todas as DIVs</div>

<script>
    $('.bloco1').replaceWith($('#conteudo'));
    $('.bloco2').replaceWith($('#conteudo'));
</script>
```

Ao executar o bloco do `script`, fica apenas uma `div` com o texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone o elemento.

Se você passar um elemento como parâmetro para o método `replaceWith`, o método irá mover o elemento para o novo local do DOM.

Se a ideia era criar um novo elemento igual ao passado como parâmetro, e manter o original em seu lugar, então crie um novo elemento usando o original como base e passe ele como parâmetro para o método:

```
$('.bloco1').replaceWith($('#conteudo').clone());
$('.bloco2').replaceWith($('#conteudo').clone());
```

Comment: Isso resolvel um problema mas gerou outro, os blocos não estão copiando os eventos aplicados nos objetos.

Comment: Realmente, listeners de eventos não fazem parte do elemento. Se você precisa que os clones dos elementos possuam os mesmos listeners, terá que aplicar os listeners neles também, ou então utilizar [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Se tiver duvidas, faça uma nova pergunta.